# Take screenshot of the whole screen unity | android

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, game-engine, rider

Im trying to screenshot the whole screenshot of phone with unity (not just the game).
I tried using System.Drawings but I couldn't get it to work even on pc. (I tried adding the dll in the project and it still doesn't work, from what I have seen in some forums it not really compatible with unity)
Do you have any solution for that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way so as to take a screenshot under Unity (but I assume that you know that) :
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html
In my project, I did a test and it works as expected - in editor mode or as a standalone app. However I cannot test it on a mobile device using Android. I guess that it could work ++

Comment: It does work but it captures the game only (not the whole screen)